# Proof of $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^+, \exists q\in \mathbb{R}^+, q<x$.

Tags: proof-verification

Prove or disprove the following statement using contradiction: $\mathbb{R}^+=\{x\in \mathbb{R} :x>0\}$, the set of positive real numbers, does not have a minimum element, also called a smallest element.

Here is my answer:
Proof: Assume that $\forall q\in \mathbb{R}^+, \exists x\in \mathbb{R}^+, x\geq q$. Let $q$ be a generic element of $\mathbb{R}^+$. Choose $x=\frac{q}{2}$, so $\frac{q}{2}\geq q$, which is a contradiction. Therefore we have proven the original statement, that the set of positive real numbers does not have a minimum element.

Are all of my statements correct? Did I leave out any neccessary rigor?
Thanks.

Comment: In the second paragraph did you mean $\exists q\in \mathbb{R}^+$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^+$, ...? Also you may not want to assume $q$ is generic.

Comment: What you've written in the title doesn't make any sense. It says, "There is a positive real number $q$ which is bigger than all the other positive real numbers"

Comment: Of course. Fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written doesn't make sense but I think you're not far off from grasping the idea of the problem. The statement that the positive real numbers does not have a least element is written like this:

$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^+, \exists q\in\mathbb{R}^+, q<x$$

meaning that no matter which positive real number $x$ you choose, I can always find a positive real number $q$ which is strictly smaller than $x$.

We can prove it by contradiction, as you've tried, by assuming the negation holds:

$$\exists x\in\mathbb{R}^+, \forall q\in\mathbb{R}^+, q\geq x$$

Since this statement must hold for all $q\in\mathbb{R}^+$, in particular is holds for $q=\frac{x}{2}$:

$$\frac{x}{2}\geq x$$

But we know that for all positive real numbers we have:

$$\frac{x}{2}<x$$

and thus we have arrived at a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The contrary of $$\forall q\in \mathbb R^+, \exists x\in\mathbb R^+: x<q$$
is $$\exists q\in\mathbb R^+: \forall x\in\mathbb R^+, x\geq q.$$
So if you make a proof by contradiction, you suppose that there is a $q\in\mathbb R^+$ s.t. $x\geq q$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^+$. This mean that $q=0$ which is a contradiction with the fact that $q\in\mathbb R^+$.